# Stripe customer A pays customer B, we take a fee

Tags: stripe-payments

I have an application, where customer A offers rooms and customer B can book a room.

In this case customer B books a room and pays customer A, so I dont hold the money on stripe. I take a cut and charge customer A once a month for all his successfull bookings.

I am not able to find information on this topic, is this even possible?

To sum it up once again:

As it is now -> Customer B books a room and the money goes to my stripe account, where I need to pay customer A myself. Also in this case I need to pay 2 x transaction fees: Customer B -> My Stripe -> Customer A.

If I hold the money myself on stripe, do I need to have PCI DSS? According to https://stripe.com/docs/security Stripe has it.

**EDIT**

I need a BaFin licence here in germany (even If I hold the money for 1 second). That is why I want to make it possible that customer B can pay customer A directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you take a look at [Destination Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges)? It may be what you are looking for.

In your case:

- Your application would be the platform account
- A would have a [Custom Stripe account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts)
- B would be a `Customer` object

Each time B books a room, you create a `Charge` by specifying the parameter `destination[account]` which will be the Custom Stripe account identifier of A. At the same time you can specify the parameter `destination[amount]` that will be less than the `Charge` amount, and the difference will be your cut. the value that you will set for `destination[amount]` will be transfered to the Custom Stripe account of A.

I think that you can easily set the recurrence of the payout (i.e. Custom Stripe Account to actual bank account) from the dashboard.

What I wrote above is really just a rephrasing of [Creating Destination Charges on Your Platform - Collecting platform fees](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#collecting-platform-fees) applied to your case.

**Zusatz**

I don't think you need an authorization from the BaFin. This what Stripe is for (among other things). At least in France, one does not need an authorization from the equivalent authority, ACPR - Banque de France.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful. Basically I need to use stripe connect destination charges. I still need to find out whether I need to have a BaFin licence, because as I understand it I still hold the money for a brief second, but thats a law question and I contacted stripe already.

Comment: See my updated answer. Put extremely simply: Stripe holds the money, not you.